# Prove a lemma about permutations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, order-theory, trees, decision-trees

Let $V$ be a set of $n$ permutations of $m$ numbers. Let $m<n<<m!$ I want to prove the following lemma:

**Lemma:** For any set of permutations $V$ there exists a pair of numbers $(a,b)$ such that $\frac{|(v\in V: a\succcurlyeq b)|}{|(v\in V: b\succcurlyeq a)|}\approx 1$.

In other words, prove that there always exists a pair of numbers such that the number of partitions where $a$ comes before $b$ is approximately equal to the number of partitions where $b$ comes before $a$.

For the sake of completeness, I want to prove this lemma in order to be able to prove the following theorem:

**Theorem:** Let $n$ be the number of permutations of $m$ numbers. Let $m<n<<m!$. We now construct a binomial tree where at the root of the tree there is the set of all $n$ permutations. Each node we select a couple of elements of the permutations $(a,b)$ and split the permutations into two nodes containing two subsets of permutations: one with each permutation where $a$ comes before $n$ and the other viceversa. A node is a leaf if it contains equal permutations. Prove that the optimal height of the tree is $O(\log{n})$.

Comment: Do you mean that the height of the tree *can be* $O(\log n)$ when we make good choices? If we make bad choices, it can definitely be worse.

Answer (score 1):

Your lemma and theorem are false. If you let $V$ be the set of permutations that switch any two adjacent elements. Then there’s $n=m-1$ permutations but for any pair $a,b$, at least $m-2$ permutations preserve their order. The ratio $(m-2)/1$ is not around 1 and the difference is $n-2$ which is not $O(\log n)$.

Similarly, the binary tree you’re constructing needs to have height $n-1$ since each test can only eliminate at most one permutation in the worst case scenario. This is not $O(\log(n))$.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a set of adjacent permutations?

Comment: $m=4$, $\{(12),(23),(34)\}$

Comment: I should add that permutations contain all of the $n$ elements.

Comment: $(12)$ is standard shorthand meaning switch 1 and 2 and send 3 to 3 and 4 to 4. The others are similar.

Comment: Am I correct that this is true if and only if $n\leq m-1$? What happens with $m<n<<m!$ ?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “this”. My example has $n=m-1$ and height $H=n-1$. I know that $n$ and $m \log(m)$ are upper bounds of H, but it’s not obvious if we can be cleverer about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145876/discussion-between-xavrojo-and-eric).